# Get unique value from array and count the no. of repetitions

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist, imacros

I have a problem while getting values from the array:
My Code is -

```
var arr = [];
for (var k =1; k<=10000; k++)`  
{  
ret = iimSet("k", k);  
      retcode = iimPlay(test)  
  var s = iimGetLastExtract(1);  
if(s == null){  
          break;  
          }  
          else {            
    arr.push(s);  

          }  
var all = arr.join(" , ");  
var final = squash(arr);  
}
```

so i am able to remove duplicates but all the results are in one line.

What I actually want to achieve is

```
     var arr = [];
                for (var k =1; k<=10000; k++)`  
                {  
                ret = iimSet("k", k);  
                      retcode = iimPlay(test)  
                  var s = iimGetLastExtract(1);  
                if(s == null){  
                          break;  
                          }  
                          else {            
                    arr.push(s);  

                          }  
                        var final = squash(arr);  

              only unqiue values
        var unq = no. of total unique values

                }

        for (var h =1; h<=unq; h++)`  
                {  
         var g=h-1;
        var c = every varaible value one by one (only unique value)
       var b = no. of times the value is repeating in the array

        ret = iimSet("c", c);
   ret = iimSet("b", b);  
        iimPlay(Save)
        }
```

So basically I want all of the values from array one by one and their no of times occurrence. I am stuck up at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I would store the number of occurrences in an object with the object's key being the value in question:

```
    var obj = {};
    for (var k =1; k<=10000; k++)
    {  
        // these three lines are your code and I dont know what they do.  But `s` is our value
        ret = iimSet("k", k);  
        retcode = iimPlay(test)  
        var s = iimGetLastExtract(1);

        if (!obj[s]) obj[s] = 0;
        obj[s]++;
    }

// the unique elements of your array are in Object.keys(obj)
// the count of occurrences are in obj[element];
```

Comment: So how do i call each value from both the objects  
`for (var k =1; k<=10000; k++)  
    `{  var a= first value from object.keys  
        `var b= first value from object.element  
`<some code here>
`}
`loops work untill the defined value.

Comment: If you know the defined value just read obj[definedValue] to get the number of occurrences.